# I cannot access domain is set Amazon routes&S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I cannot access domain whose bluehacking.com is set Amazon routes&S3.
I bought  bluehacking.com in Amazon routes.Now I want to access bluehacking.com.So,I went to Amazon S3,made bucket whose name is bluehacking.com and set Permission of Bucket Policy like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bluehacking.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I upload index.html in Static website hosting.
However when I access bluehacking.com,"You cannot access this site" is shown.index.html is not shown. What is wrong in my setting?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set public read access to your bucket:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::bluehacking.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```